# What MarkLogic features are not supported in Marklogic DHS

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

What `MarkLogic` features are not supported in `Marklogic DHS`.
(*Triggers, URI-rewriter, HTTP callouts* to name a few)

Answer (score 4):

Although DHS is a different product than MarkLogic Server, the "gap" in features is constantly getting smaller. Most, if not all, limitations come from the fact that running Data Hub as a cloud service has an added layer of security requirements.

Very often, these requirements are dictated by the cloud providers themselves and the need to certify the service with various security standards that customers demand.

Having said that, it's best to look at the use case and its requirements rather than thinking in "limitations" since every software product has limitations (including the MarkLogic Server).

Is there a specific use case or set of use cases you're looking to implement with DHS?